# Wordpress Emoji Disable Code Not Working

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function

I tried disabling the emoji code in wordpress with the following code. It worked for a little while but after the latest upgrade, I see those damn emojis again. This is the code I'm using in child theme functions.

```
/**
 * Disable the emoji's
 */
function disable_emojis() {
 remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
 remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
 remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
 remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' ); 
 remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
 remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' ); 
 remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
 add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojis_tinymce' );
 add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', 'disable_emojis_remove_dns_prefetch', 10, 2 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_emojis' );

/**
 * Filter function used to remove the tinymce emoji plugin.
 * 
 * @param array $plugins 
 * @return array Difference betwen the two arrays
 */
function disable_emojis_tinymce( $plugins ) {
 if ( is_array( $plugins ) ) {
 return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
 } else {
 return array();
 }
}

/**
 * Remove emoji CDN hostname from DNS prefetching hints.
 *
 * @param array $urls URLs to print for resource hints.
 * @param string $relation_type The relation type the URLs are printed for.
 * @return array Difference betwen the two arrays.
 */
function disable_emojis_remove_dns_prefetch( $urls, $relation_type ) {
 if ( 'dns-prefetch' == $relation_type ) {
 /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/formatting.php */
 $emoji_svg_url = apply_filters( 'emoji_svg_url', 'https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2/svg/' );

$urls = array_diff( $urls, array( $emoji_svg_url ) );
 }

return $urls;
}
```

But no matter what I try, I still see the emojis cdn and css being called in pingdom tools. Please help! 
My website is [bewitcheryinc.com](http://bewitcheryinc.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available, [Disable Emojis](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-emojis/).

Alternatively, you can replace the smilies with the original versions from previous versions of WordPress using [Classic Smilies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-smilies/).

You can also remove the DNS prefetch by returning false on filter `emoji_svg_url`:

```
add_filter( 'emoji_svg_url', '__return_false' );
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you but I already have that filter in the original code. It doesn't work. I didn't want to add an additional plugin either. Was hoping to use code only. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code changed to this:

```
/**
 * Remove emoji CDN hostname from DNS prefetching hints.
 *
 * @param  array  $urls          URLs to print for resource hints.
 * @param  string $relation_type The relation type the URLs are printed for.
 * @return array                 Difference betwen the two arrays.
 */
function disable_emojis_remove_dns_prefetch( $urls, $relation_type ) {

    if ( 'dns-prefetch' === $relation_type ) {

        // Strip out any URLs referencing the WordPress.org emoji location.
        $emoji_svg_url_bit = 'https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/';
        foreach ( $urls as $key => $url ) {
            if ( strpos( $url, $emoji_svg_url_bit ) !== false ) {
                unset( $urls[ $key ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $urls;
}
```